# Google AdWords - How to correctly use Auto-Tagging and UTM variables in AdWords?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-ads-api, utm

Let me preface this question with a little background information:

1. I have a web based system that takes in data from the Google Analytics API and displays that information based upon each clients needs via a web interface.
2. I use unique URLs for each source/campaign ( Google AdWords, LinkedIn, Facebook, Display Ad Networks, etc. ) containing 'utm' variables and the system generated values.  Example:  url.com/?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=PPC&utm_content=1234&utm_campaign=This-is-the-campaign-name
3. Google Analytics is the repository, since a large majority of clients use it on their websites, it's a natural fit to use them as the workhorse for data capturing.
4. All of the clients have active Google AdWords campaigns, connected Google Analytics accounts, and they have enabled Auto-Tagging.
5. When I test a Google text ad, the link that is populated in the web browser is similar to the following:  url.com/?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=PPC&utm_content=1234&utm_campaign=This-is-the-campaign-name&gclid=123xyz

My current dilemma is centered around AdWords campaigns with Auto-Tagging enabled.  The data capture process for all sources ( excluding Google AdWords ) works fine.  I have unique tracking codes populated in the 'utm_content' variable, therefore when I call the Google Analytics API, this tracking code acts as my unique identifier.  For all Google AdWords campaigns, I update all the destination links within the ad creative to include the system generated URLs that also include the prepopulated values.  When viewing the reporting in Google Analytics, the variables/values are non-existent, it is as if Google completely disregards these values and uses a back-channel from Google AdWords to Google Analytics to input the campaign properties.  For these Google AdWords campaigns, the visits are not lost, but rather they are associated to the standard Google AdWords campaign/ad group in Google Analytics.

Here is a list of things that I do know:

1. From what I have read, disabling Auto-Tagging would fix this issue and allow the 'utm' variables and their values to be passed from Google AdWords into Google Analytics.  The consequence of disabling Auto-Tagging would be the loss of click to conversion and cost data.
2. KISSmetrics has documented a similar issue when working with clients that also use Google Analytics.  Links that contain the 'gclid', Example: url.com/?gclid=123xyz ( Auto-Tagging enabled ), will not have any additional information logged ( campaign source, medium, etc. ).  Links that also contain the 'utm' variables, Example:  url.com/?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=PPC&utm_content=1234&utm_campaign=This-is-the-campaign-name&gclid=123xyz, this information is passed to KISSmetrics.  For this second scenario, I am assuming the KISSmetrics javascript is reading the URL variables and values.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

1. I am trying to avoid having to add a proprietary javascript that reads the URL variables and values and then posts that information to an external URL.
2. I do not want to add line items to the current Google Analytics javascript ( example:  custom variables ).
3. I am looking for an 'out-of-the-box' solution that perhaps takes into consideration AdWords ValueTrack parameters.  My familiarity with these variables is limited, therefore I can not determine if one of these values can be used as a unique identifier to later reference when I access the data using the Google Analytics API.  Or as an alternative, using a Google AdWords dimension to do the same.  See http://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/adwords.
4. I would like to determine if it is possible to continue with the methodology of generating unique URLs, assigning them to Google AdWords campaigns, and taking the results of those campaigns from Google Analytics via their API, without compromising the click to conversion and cost data ( disabling Auto-Tagging ).

Thanks in advance for reading through my plight and any feedback you provide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

So you are correct.  When Google Analytics sees both UTM params and the auto-tagging GCLID, it discards the UTM params in favor of the GCLID.

However... acknowledging that this is an issue, especially since AdWords advertisers that use their Conversion Import feature often use both UTM and GCLID, they enabled an override switch in Google Analytics accounts that allows the use of both.

You can learn more about it in their FAQ at https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033981?hl=en

I think this should solve your problem.

Jon

Comment: thank you, so this won't result in double reporting inside analytics interface?